# android emulator clips my activity (ok in landscape)

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout, clip

I am running AVD "Google API Level 11" (platform 3.0) and want to understand why my login 
activity is not taking up the entire screen real estate of the emulator. I am using fill_parent in the appropiate places. In landscape It looks ok, see below

http://www.akersacademy.com/images/robert/landscape.png

in portrait, the emulator has more room to use, but it seems to clip
my help button (question mark image)

http://www.akersacademy.com/images/robert/portrait.png

Here is my login_activity.xml file, can anyone help me with whats happening

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">


    <ImageView  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:src="@drawable/wfm_login_v2"                        
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TableLayout            
        android:stretchColumns="1"          
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="@string/loginActivityUserId"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="24sp" 
                android:gravity="right"/>

            <EditText 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/loginHelpButton"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/question" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="@string/loginActivityPassword"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24.5sp" />

            <EditText 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/black_32x32" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

                <TextView android:text=""
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:weightSum="10">
                    <Button android:text="Login"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_weight="5"
                            android:textSize="24.5sp"/>
                    <Button android:text="Cancel"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="5"
                            android:textSize="24.5sp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/black_32x32" />

        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your components seem to be perfectly aligned with the WFM-PDA-borders on top there.
Are you sure that's not all the screen estate you have?
How does it look on a real device?

Apart from that - and I'm shooting from my hip here: try setting android:shrinkColumns="*" on your TableLayout, see if it helps...

Also: Check your AndroidManifest.xml-file, maybe you can do something with the supports-screen-attribute:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:resizeable="true"/>
```

Comment: I agree with @DKIT. You say that "In landscape It looks ok", I would disagree. Somewhere, somehow a width is being specified, I'd look in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: thanks for your replies, I created the project from scratch, so i have the very basic AndroidManifest.xml there is, with no references to support-screens. I did notice how the componets are under and no wider than the WFM-PDA-borders on top. But i would think that the whole app, (including the border at top) should be as wide as the screen, as wide as the signal/battery/time status bar up there. I did put the supports-screens tag in but it behaves the same. maybe its just the emulator, I do not have a tablet to test on so just wanted to get coding via emulator.

Comment: dang, I also tried android:shrinkColumns="*" in my <TableLayout> but no effect